# Fedora 16 Drag Files to Desktop

Tags: gnome, fedora, gnome3

How can I put files on the desktop?

I've tried both dragging files to the desktop and copying files to ~/Desktop, but nothing shows on my desktop. Is this just Fedora or am I missing something?

Comment: are your files on Desktop when you try with     ls ~/Desktops?

Comment: Assuming the extra s at the end of your sentence is a typo, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do this with the base installation.